# How to put a variable in a def statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to have a variable in a `def` statement so that when I use the `def` statement, the variable will be defined.

For example:

```
def pizza():
    cheese = 7

pizza()
```

and then `cheese` will become equal to 7 THIS IS THE FIRST EXAMPLE

Even if I did, for example:
THIS IS ANOTHER EXAMPLE

```
def pizza():
    cheese = 7
def pomegranate():
    cheese = 6
pizza()
```

and `cheese` will be set to 7

Is it possible to do this? I have both python 3 and 2.7. My python program tells me that `cheese` doesn't exist. How else can I do it (without an `if` statement if possible)?

Comment: It's hard to give you a recommendation, because you didn't give us much help on how you plan to use this.  Your posted code does not produce the problem you state.  We can't tell whether you need a parameter to each routine, a return value, or a (shudder) global variable.

Comment: Your posted code has *two* variables named **cheese**, one in each function.  There is no such variable in the main program.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question? There's no string anywhere in the code, just variables and numbers.

Comment: Maybe you don't understand the difference between a string and a variable?

Comment: You need to read or continue reading a tutorial.

Comment: None of your code examples put a string in a `def` statement. They define a local variable, but that's all. You must mean something else—do as TigerhawkT3 suggests...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `global` declaration so that it will write to a global variable instead of a variable local to the function.

```
def pizza():
    global cheese
    cheese = 7

def pomegranate():
    global cheese
    cheese = 6

pizza()
print(cheese)
```

But this is generally considered poor programming style. Functions should usually communicate through parameters and return values, not global variables.